# jQuery get selected option and select another select

Tags: jquery, html

I have done a form which copies billing fields to shipping fields if they want the same details, im having troubles with the title - i have a selevct options list with mr, mrs, miss etc... what i need to do is when its changed on one to then make the other selected as well

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jquery [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$('#sel2').val($('#sel1')​.val());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HpuZz/2)

Comment: thats just passing the value, the lists are identical - i need to make selected based on whats selected on the other select list

Comment: and how is my demo different?

Comment: you're welcome.. i added the demo after you asked to make things clear

Comment: it seems to conflict i think with my other live change.... any thoughts? $(".shipping").live('change', function () {
            var billingId = $(this).attr('id').replace('_shipping_', '_billing_');
            $('#' + billingId).val($(this).val());
        });

        $('#same_shipping_address_title').live('change', function () {
            $('#same_shipping_address_title').val($('#same_billing_address_title').val());
        });

Comment: same_billing_address_title sounds suspicious.. could you update the fiddle to demonstrate your problem?